# Add a long and ulong in C#

Tags: c#, math

An api I am using has a `ulong` field (I can't change this). I need to adjust this field by the a `long` amount (could be an `int` too). However I can't add these togeather: `Operator '+' is ambiguous on operands of type 'ulong' and 'long'`.

I can't convert the `long` to a `ulong` because I will lose the sign, I can't convert the `ulong` to a `long` because I could lose part of the value.

Ultimately I want to attempt to adjust the value, if it would cause a wrap I want to return `false` and not finish the adjustment. If it doesn't wrap I want to finish the adjustment and return true;  I can do this part, but only if I can figure out a a way to add the two fields together in the first place.

```
public ulong Value;
public bool AdjustValue(long amount)
{
    // Operator '+' is ambiguous on operands of type 'ulong' and 'long'
    ulong adjustValue = Value + amount; 

    if (amount < 0 && adjustValue > Value)
        return false;
    if (amount > 0 && adjustValue < Value)
        return false;

    Value = adjustValue;
    return true;
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Not clear what you want to do but perhaps you can find the solution using the BigInteger class from System.Numerics

Comment: `if (long < 0) ulong -= (ulong)(-long); else ulong += (ulong)long;`?

Comment: @itsme86 - perfect, I had tried that but missed the `-`long part! Thanks

Comment: No problem. Seems kludgy to me still and probably generates more IL instructions than a simple add operation. Might be a better solution out there somewhere.

Comment: Maybe convert both to decimal and then cast result back?

Comment: `ulong.MaxValue` is _very_ large. Are you sure you really could ever actually exceed this value?

Comment: @PeterDuniho - Probably not, but it's easier to write the logic in now - than to track the bug down 3 years later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone's going to hate this answer, but you *could* use the decimal data type, since it is capable of storing 28-29 significant digits and 2^64 only has 20 digits.

Naturally using a floating point data type incurs a bit of overhead in terms of performance, but on the other hand this code is really easy to read, and may have better branch prediction/pipelining than a solution that requires `if`.

```
public static ulong Add(this ulong baseValue, long offset)
{
    decimal adjustedValue = (decimal)baseValue + offset;
    return (ulong)adjustedValue;
}
```

If you overflow, the system will throw a decent enough `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, but you could also roll your own:

```
public static ulong Add(this ulong baseValue, long offset)
{
    decimal adjustedValue = (decimal)baseValue + offset;
    if (adjustedValue > ulong.MaxValue) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Too big to fit!");
    if (adjustedValue < ulong.MinValue) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Too small to fit!");
    return (ulong)adjustedValue;
}
```

Comment: I was reading back through answers, and now that I have grown as a developer I think this is actually the best answer having learned not to fear throwing exceptions and actually use them where appropriate.

Comment: @AnthonyNichols: That's fine...it's your question. That said, it's important to keep in mind that even without exceptions, the `decimal` type incurs an enormous performance overhead as compared to types that the CPU understands, and of course the exceptions themselves are very costly. This is fine for code where these kinds of calculations occur infrequently (which may well be the case in your scenario), but it would be unwise to use this approach where the calculations dominate the code execution time.

Answer (score 6):

For readability, you may prefer the suggestion in the comment:

```
adjustValue = Value;
if (amount < 0)
    adjustValue -= (ulong)(-amount);
else
    adjustValue += (ulong)amount;
```

This makes clear how you expect the math to work.

However…

The representation of integers in practically every modern hardware CPU is two's complement. One of the reasons is that math using two's complement binary numbers has a very nice property: you get the same binary representation for addition and subtraction whether you're dealing with signed or unsigned values.

This means that you can just cast the adjustment value to `ulong` to do your addition. According to the C# language rules, the cast will simply reinterpret the signed value's binary representation as unsigned. And adding the unsigned value will have exactly the same effect as if you'd added a signed value with that same binary representation.

Here's a code example that shows this working:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ulong[] values = { ulong.MinValue, ulong.MaxValue, long.MaxValue };
    long[] adjust = { 0, 1, -1, long.MinValue, long.MaxValue };

    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < adjust.Length; j++)
        {
            ulong value = values[i];

            bool result = AdjustValue(adjust[j], ref value);
            Console.WriteLine($"{values[i]} + {adjust[j]} = {values} (overflow: {!result})");
        }
    }
}

static bool AdjustValue(long amount, ref ulong value)
{
    ulong adjustValue = value + (ulong)amount;

    if (amount < 0 && adjustValue > value)
        return false;
    if (amount > 0 && adjustValue < value)
        return false;

    value = adjustValue;
    return true;
}
```

Note: by default, math operations are runtime are unchecked. However, there is a compiler switch that can change this. If you are compiling your code with that switch enabled, forcing checked arithmetic operations, you will need to wrap the above in an `unchecked` block to avoid getting overflow exceptions.